# Retrieve name of the Setting from app.config file

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, settings

I need to retrieve the name of the key setting from app.config file.

For instance:

My app.config file:

```
<setting name="IGNORE_CASE" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
</setting>
```

I know i can retrieve the value using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.IGNORE_CASE
```

Is there a way to get the string "IGNORE_CASE" from my key setting ?

Comment: Not available just yet at time of writing, but in C# 6.0 you will be able to use the `nameof` operator: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2427047-add-nameof-operator-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(((System.Configuration.SettingsProperty)enumerator.Current).Name);
}
```

**Edit:** with foreach approach as suggested

```
foreach (System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", property.Name, property.DefaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for both answer, but in this way i am forced to loop for all settings.

Answer (score 8):

The sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) shows how to loop over all settings to read their key & value.

Excerpt for convenience:

```
// Get the AppSettings section.        
// This function uses the AppSettings property
// to read the appSettings configuration 
// section.
public static void ReadAppSettings()
{
    // Get the AppSettings section.
    NameValueCollection appSettings =
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    // Get the AppSettings section elements.
    for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.Count; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("#{0} Key: {1} Value: {2}",
        i, appSettings.GetKey(i), appSettings[i]);
    }
}
```