# Setting call with an index

Tags: c#, vb.net

I just deleted my question to reformulate it a better way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876733/retrieve-name-of-the-setting-from-app-config-file/7876823#7876823) didn't really helped me either.

I can assign my **user** settings this way:

```
MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default.settingname1 = "mystring1";
MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default.settingname2 = "mystring2";
...
MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default.settingname300 = "mystring300";
```

To access this setting value, what i can do is

```
string newstring = MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default.settingname1;
```

**What I want, is being able to access this setting this way, with an index i that varies from 1 to 300, I don't want to make a loop. I am searching something like:**

```
int i = random.Next(1, 301);
string newstring = MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default.----settingnamei-----
```

I am pretty sure there is an easy way to do it, I just can't find it.

thanks for reading

**EDIT**
Three reasons why I dont like the linked question's answers:

-I have to go through a 300 iterations foreach loop to find the 1 string I am searching

-This way I can only get DefaultValue and what I want is **the actual value** of my string

-App settings is not user settings. What I am asking for is to get the values from Settings.cs

Comment: The question you linked is a good solution. What didn't you like about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve name of the Setting from app.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876733/retrieve-name-of-the-setting-from-app-config-file)

Comment: What is the class `rdm`? What is the purpose of trying to use your indexed member in this way?

Comment: Looks like you're just trying to pull in a random setting? Why?

Comment: random is because its a game, and i have to call a random event :-)

Comment: @Kingpin Maybe something like this `object defObj = MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default;   defObj.GetType().GetField("settingname" + i).SetValue(defObj, "mystring" + i);`

Comment: @L.B this looks very attractive and hot, gonna try it now with GetValue

Comment: @L.B I tried it but I don't really know how to use it, because I don't know the string inside my name so I can't get its value... I tried:
    **newstring = (string)defObj .GetType().GetField("settingname" + i).GetValue(defObj);**

but it returns null

Comment: @Kingpin Maybe it is a property. Have you tried `GetProperty`? Or it is a `static field`.

Comment: yea its a property, i can access it through:
 **newstring= (string)defObj.GetType().GetProperty(Properties.Settings.Default.settingnamei);**
but its still the same problem: I can't call it with an index i inside the name. plus I can't get its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
        int i = random.Next(1, 301);
        string newstring = MySolution.Properties.Settings.Default["settingname" + i].ToString();
```